# Android fabric twitter authorize callback is not called

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I have started using Twitter Fabric for Android. Login with TwitterLoginButton is working fine,
but in some cases I don't need to use TwitterLoginButton, I just need to get user token and secret.
The code looks right, twitter login form is opened but callback is called at all.

```
TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
authClient.authorize(TwitterSettingsActivity.this, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
     @Override
     public void success(Result<TwitterSession> twitterSessionResult) {
         Logger.e(TAG, "ok");
     }

     @Override
     public void failure(TwitterException e) {
         Logger.e(TAG, "failure error", e);
     }
});
```

I guess I need to add some handling in onActivityResult but there is no info about it in the doc https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/request-email

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're right that you need to add some handling in an onActivityResult to get the callback. To pass the Activity’s result back so that your callback receives it, you can do the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the auth client.
        authClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

This is essentially what the `TwitterLoginButton` is doing in its `TwitterLoginButton#onActivityResult` method.

Comment: i have same problem but i am using fragment instead of activity that is only difference

Comment: i am also declare `TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(LoginMainActivity.TWITTER_KEY, LoginMainActivity.TWITTER_SECRET);
            Fabric.with(getActivity(), new Twitter(authConfig));`
inside onCreateView()